# Handling exception in Rails in dev/production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception

For handling exceptions I decided to use `Exception_notifier` gem. Here is the code I use in `/config/enviroments/development.rb`

```
  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
    :email_prefix => "[ERROR] ",
    :sender_address => '"dev-Notifier" <error@my_emails.com>',
    :exception_recipients => ['error@my_emails.com']
```

If I make some syntax failure, for example:

```
@article = Article.fixnd(params[:id])
```

I will receive the error email about it.

But if I set to the URL line this address:

```
http://localhost:3001/articlesssssss
```

I'll get an error, but the email is not sent. The same behavior if I set to the url bad address (404 error).

What I have to set up, if I would like to receive email about every error in the app (also about the last 2 errors above)?

This is the part I use in `ApplicationController`:

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer to this in the Exception_notification docs:

https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/#rack-x-cascade-header

> ### Rack X-Cascade Header
>
> Some rack apps (Rails in particular) utilize the "X-Cascade" header to
>   pass the request-handling responsibility to the next middleware in the
>   stack.
>
> Rails' routing middleware uses this strategy, rather than raising an
>   exception, to handle routing errors (e.g. 404s); to be notified
>   whenever a 404 occurs, set this option to "false."
>
> #### `:ignore_cascade_pass`
>
> *Boolean, default: true*
>
> Set to false to trigger notifications when another rack middleware
>   sets the "X-Cascade" header to "pass."